# Using "object<<ostream" syntax for a template argument rather than "object.operator<<<type>(ostream)"

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, operator-overloading

I know that << operator can be overloaded as method function as well. The problem comes when i am using template arguments.

I've realised that i need to specify the class and as such i wrote < A > before operator<< .

Where should i write < A > if i want to use the object< < ostream syntax ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>

using namespace std;



class A
{
private:
    int x;

public :

A(int i = 0)
{
    x = i;

}
A operator + (A temp)
{
    return x + temp.x;
}

template <class T>
ostream & operator << (ostream &);
};

template <class T>
ostream& A::operator<<(ostream &o)
{
o<<x;
return o;

}

int main()
{
A a(33),b(-21);
(a+b).operator<<<A>(cout);
//a+b<<cout; ????
}
```

Comment: You need to overload a free standing binary operator funtion for stream output.behavior.

Comment: Either the template-parameters are deduced by the type of a parameter, or you should write (...).operator <<<A>(...) always. Why do you want to use cout as the right parameter, while you normally shift the things from the right into the stream?

Comment: Is there any need for the template parameter?

Comment: No, there is no actual need for it. I'm using it as a template because i want to accommodate with using template parameters.

Comment: Just don't use template for operators (unless they can be deduced by the passed types). Otherwise, `(a+b).operator<< <A>(cout);` is essentially the only way to call that operator.